# iOS Interactive Map application?

Tags: ios, dictionary, mapkit, interactive

I'm trying to make an application that is a map of my High School, in which the user can click a button to search for either a room or a locker.... My goal was to have the room/locker number correspond to a point on several hidden "number lines" in different areas on the Nib file/display, and when a certain input is received, the corresponding number would light up or show its location (i.e. I don't have to enter every locker location for instance, only the first and last one in each hallway, and the number line generated between the values I enter would represent all the lockers in-between).

I'm using Xcode 4.3.3 if that helps.... Structure-wise I wanted to use the Tabbed-application template and have one tab for the actual Map, one for entering which locker you are looking for, and one for entering which room you want to find. I'm new to iOS programming so I don't know if there is a better way to accomplish something like this, and I am open to any suggestions or advice. Thanks!

Comment: This is not an xcode question. Untag xcode, tag as iOS

Comment: You can do a prototype first; then you'll see weak and strong sides.

Answer (score 0):

You could marry [MapKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html) with your own database in which you'd define the coordinates for rooms, banks of lockers, etc. See [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/) which shows how to integrate maps in an app. I can imagine that you could define [`MKOverlay`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlay_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) objects for rooms and ranges of lockers. Or you could simply define [`MKAnnotation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) objects for points of interest (cafeteria, etc.).

But some combination of overlays and annotations using MapKit seems like a logical solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might also use the [MapBox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mobile) to do this, along with an interactivity layer as described at http://mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/crashcourse/tooltips/